# Riemann sum $\int x^m dx$?

Tags: integration, riemann-sum

I'm trying to find the Riemann integral of $x^m$ between $a$ and $b$ with $b>a$.

So far I have managed to get $$\int_a^b x^m~dx=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(a^m \times \frac{b-a}{n} \times \sum_{r=1}^n q^{(r-1)m}\right)$$

$$=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left(a^m \times \frac{b-a}{n} \times \frac{q^{nm}-1}{q^m-1}\right)$$ but I don't know how to evaluate this limit?

Any help?

I forgot to mention the points of division are $$a=aq^0,aq,aq^2,...aq^{r-1},aq^r,...aq^{n-1},aq^n=b$$ and I'm using the left end point to calculate the sum apologies.

Comment: What is $q$ supposed to be?

Comment: $q$ is the is used in the term for the left endpoint which I'm using to calculate the sum, my bad I neglected to mention this will update now.

Comment: Updated, sorry for any inconvenience.

Comment: Do you know the connection between Riemannian integral and differential of a function?

Comment: $F'(x)=f(x) \iff \int f(x) dx = F(x)+\phi$? I don't think I'm supposed to be using any link between the derivative and integral when answering this question.

Comment: @Ryan your Riemann sums are not correctly written. If you're using the points $aq^r$, $0 \le r \le n$ as the points of division of $[a,b]$, then your sums should be $$\sum_{r = 1}^n (aq^r)^m(aq^r - aq^{r-1})$$

Comment: I'm using the points $aq^{r-1}$ though.

Comment: @Ryan right, so where did the $(b - a)/n$ come from?

Comment: The length of any given sub-interval in my partition of $[a,b]$ there are $n$ such sub-intervals giving $n \times \frac{b-a}{n}=b-a$ i.e the length of the interval $[a,b]$ which is the length of the $x$-axis I'm trying to find the area over.

Comment: @Ryan not if the subintervals have varying lengths. So what are your subintervals?

Comment: The sub-intervals each have length $\frac{b-a}{n}$ I have defined my sum this way. I.e $$ [a= aq^0, aq] , [aq ,aq^2] ,..., [aq^{r-1} , aq^r] ,..., [aq^{n-1} , aq^n=b] $$ are my sub-intervals.

Comment: @Ryan If your partition is as you describe it, then they most certainly do **not** have the same lengths:  the length of the $r^{\rm th}$ subinterval is $$ aq^r - aq^{r-1} = aq^{r-1}(q-1)$$ which is very clearly a nonconstant function of $r$.

Comment: @heropup Thanks for that I have no idea why I was thinking that each interval was of the same length, guess I should be able to go ahead and do the problem now thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Assume $0 < a < b$.  Then for every positive integer $n$ let $q = (b/a)^{1/n} > 1$, and consider the partition $$\bigcup_{r=0}^{n-1} \, [aq^r, aq^{r+1}) = [a,b).$$  Then with $f(x) = x^m$, consider $$\begin{align*} S_n &= \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} (aq^{r+1} - aq^r)f(aq^r) \\ &= a^{m+1}(q-1) \sum_{r=0}^{n-1} (q^{m+1})^r \\ &= a^{m+1}(q-1) \frac{(q^{m+1})^n-1}{q^{m+1} - 1} \\ &= \left((aq^n)^{m+1} - a^{m+1}\right) \frac{q-1}{q^{m+1}-1} \\ &= \frac{b^{m+1} - a^{m+1}}{\sum_{k=0}^m q^k}. \end{align*}$$  This is because $aq^n = b$.  Now note that it is only the denominator of $S_n$ that is a function of $n$ through $q$.  So, as $n \to \infty$, $q \to 1$ since $b > a$.  Hence $$\lim_{n \to \infty} S_n = \frac{b^{m+1} - a^{m+1}}{m+1}.$$

---

Of course, the evaluation of the limit at the end is problematic if $m$ is not itself a nonnegative integer.  I leave it to the reader to consider the general case where $m \ne 0$ of the limit $$\lim_{q \to 1} \frac{q^m - 1}{q-1}.$$